# Unable to pass a function to child component

Tags: swiftui

All i want to do is allow the user to make a choice in UserEditView that will be reflected back to the parent EventEditView but i cant!

I have the following component::

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI


struct UserEditView: View {

    var user: User?
    @State private var is_read_only: Bool = true
    @State private var is_user_same_as_event_creator: Bool = true
    
    @State private var email = "jcasasma22il@gmail.com"
    @State private var phone_number = 22
    @State private var password = "jcasasmail"

    @State private var state = "new"
    @State private var height_feet: Int = 5
    @State private var height_inches: Int = 10

    @State private var name = "juan"
    @State private var age: Int = 1
    @State private var bio = "i like big butts"
    @State private var industry = ""
    @State private var home_town = ""
    @State private var has_kids: HasKids = .no

    @State private var gender = Gender.male
    @State private var interested_sex = InterestedSex.female
    @State private var is_authenticated = false
    
    @State private var images: Image?
    @State private var is_image_picked_presented = false
    @State private var imageData: Data?

    @State private var latitude: Float?
    @State private var longitude: Float?
    @AppStorage("user_data") var user_data: Data?

    @EnvironmentObject var locationManager: LocationManager
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var sheet_manager: SheetManager


    let user_util = UserUtil()


    
    init(user:User?){
        let userData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: user_data ?? Data())


        if let user = user{
            
            
            _email = State(initialValue: user.email!)
            _phone_number = State(initialValue: Int(user.phone_number!) ?? 0 )
            _height_feet = State(initialValue: user.height_feet!)
            _height_inches = State(initialValue: user.height_inches! )
            _name = State(initialValue: user.name)
            _age = State(initialValue: user.age)
            _bio = State(initialValue: user.bio)
            _industry = State(initialValue: user.industry)
            _home_town = State(initialValue: user.home_town)
            _has_kids = State(initialValue: user.has_kids ? .yes : .no)
            _gender = State(initialValue: user.gender == .male ? .male : .female)            
            _is_user_same_as_event_creator = State(initialValue: user.created_by == userData?.created_by)

            _is_read_only = State(initialValue: is_user_same_as_event_creator)


        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
 
                
                Button("Yes") {
                    print("Yes")

                    
                }
                
                Button("No") {
                    print("NO")

                }


                Button("maybe") {
                    print("maybe")

                }


          
                
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $is_authenticated, content: {
                BottomNavBarView()
            })
            .onAppear {

            }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Edit profile")
            .popup(with: sheet_manager)
        }
    }

    private func back_button() -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                Text("Back")
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
    }

    private func handle_signup() {
        if state == "new" {
            sign_up_with_email()
        }
    }

    private func sign_up_with_email() {
//        user_util.create_user_with_email(
//            email: email,
//            password: password,
//            name: name,
//            bio: bio,
//            gender: gender,
//            interested_sex: interested_sex,
//            imageData: imageData!,
////            latitude: latitude,
////            longitude: longitude,
//            heightFeet: height_feet,
//            heightInches: height_inches
//        ) { result in
//            switch result {
//            case .success(let token):
//                is_authenticated = true
//            case .failure(let error):
//                print("[VIEW]User creation failed. Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
//            }
//        }
    }

    enum AuthenticationError: Error {
        case userCreationFailed
    }
}

struct UserEditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UserEditView(user:nil).environmentObject(SheetManager())
    }
}
```

I need to get the button pressed to the parent component

here is the parent component, but i get an error::

```
// EventEditView

import SwiftUI




struct EventEditView: View {
    //    UI
    @State private var is_event_saved = false
    @State private var is_read_only: Bool = true
    @State private var is_user_same_as_event_creator: Bool = true
    @State private var is_loading: Bool = true
    
    var event: Event?
    
    //    event
    @State private var location = ""
    @State private var description = ""
    @State private var state = "new"
    @State private var time: Date = Date()
    @State private var latitude:Double?
    @State private var longtitude:Double?
    
    @State private var event_applications:[EventApplication] = []
    @State private var event_applications_users:[User] = []

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    //    user
    @AppStorage("user_latitude") var user_latitude: Double?
    @AppStorage("user_longitude") var user_longitude: Double?
    @AppStorage("user_data") var user_data: Data?
    
    private var event_util = EventUtil()
    private var user_util = UserUtil()
    private var event_application_util = EventApplicationUtil()
    
    @State private var is_date_selected: String?

    
    init(event: Event?) {
        if let event = event {
            print("Event passed")
            let userData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: user_data ?? Data())
            
            self.event = event
            
            
            self._location = State(initialValue: event.location ?? "")
            self._description = State(initialValue: event.description ?? "")
            self._state = State(initialValue: event.state ?? "")
            self._latitude = State(initialValue: event.latitude ?? 0.0)
            self._longtitude = State(initialValue: event.longitude ?? 0.0)
            let date_formatter = DateFormatter()
            date_formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
            let eventTime = date_formatter.date(from: event.time)
            self._time = State(initialValue: eventTime ?? Date())
            
            
            self._is_user_same_as_event_creator = State(initialValue: event.created_by == userData?.created_by)
            
            self._is_read_only = State(initialValue: is_user_same_as_event_creator)
            
            
            
        } else {
            self.event = nil
            self._is_user_same_as_event_creator = State(initialValue: true)
            self._is_read_only = State(initialValue: false)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Form() {
            


            
            if !is_loading && event_applications.count>0 {
                Section(header: Text("Users that applied")) {
                    
                    List {
                        ForEach(event_applications.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: UserEditView(user: event_applications_users[index] , onButtonPress:handleButtonPress),
                                label: {
                                    Text(event_applications_users[index].name)
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
            
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit Event")
        .onAppear {
            handle_get_event_applications()
        }
    
    
    }
    
    
    func handleButtonPress(_ action: ButtonAction) {
        switch action {
        case .yes:
            // Handle "Yes" button press
            break
        case .no:
            // Handle "No" button press
            break
        case .maybe:
            // Handle "Maybe" button press
            break
        }
    }
    
    
  
}
```

error::

```
/Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/dayt/dayt/UI/Views/Event/EventEditView.swift:76:16 Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure
```

For the record, ihave two nested navigators to get to this page.

here they are:::

```
import SwiftUI

struct BottomNavBarView: View {
    struct TabItem {
        var title: String
        var destination: AnyView
        var image_system_name: String
    }

    @AppStorage("bottom_navigator_height") var bottom_navigator_height: Double?

    let tabs = [
        TabItem(title: "Messages", destination: AnyView(MessagesListView()), image_system_name: "2.circle"),
        TabItem(title: "Events", destination: AnyView(EventsNavigatorView()), image_system_name: "1.circle"),
        TabItem(title: "Settings", destination: AnyView(SettingsView()), image_system_name: "3.circle"),
    ]

    @State private var selectedTab = 1

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            ForEach(tabs.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                NavigationView {
                    tabs[index].destination
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: tabs[index].image_system_name)
                    Text(tabs[index].title)
                }
                .tag(index)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Use the stored height if available, otherwise set a default value
            bottom_navigator_height = bottom_navigator_height ?? 100.0
        }
    }
}
```

here is the other one::

```
import SwiftUI

struct EventsNavigatorView: View {
    @AppStorage("bottom_event_navigator_height") var bottom_event_navigator_height: Double?

    struct TabItem {
        var title: String
        var view: AnyView
    }

    let tabs = [
        TabItem(title: "Approved Applications", view: AnyView(EventsApplicationsListView())),
        TabItem(title: "Event finder", view: AnyView(EventMatcherView())),
        TabItem(title: "Events created", view: AnyView(MyEventsListView())),
    ]

    @State private var selectedTab = 1
    @State private var userID: String?

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                ForEach(0..<tabs.count) { index in
                    tabs[index].view
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "\(index + 1).circle")
                            Text(tabs[index].title)
                        }
                        .tag(index)
                }
            } .onAppear {
                bottom_event_navigator_height = geometry.size.height
                print("bottom_event_navigator_height:::::::::  ",bottom_event_navigator_height)

            }
           
        }
    }
}

struct MyEventsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // Your implementation for "My events" view
        Text("My Events Content")
    }
}
```

i trid this but i got the same error::

```
     if !is_loading && event_applications.count > 0 {
                       Section(header: Text("Users that applied")) {
                           List {
                               ForEach(event_applications.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                                   NavigationLink(
                                       destination: UserEditView(user: event_applications_users[index], onButtonPress: handleButtonPress),
                                       label: {
                                           Text(event_applications_users[index].name)
                                       }
                                   )
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
```

I tried everything chatgpt proposed and no luck.
i didnt see any stackoverflow posts with this issue

I tried this but no luck either::

```
// EventEditView

import SwiftUI




struct EventEditView: View {
    //    UI
    @State private var is_event_saved = false
    @State private var is_read_only: Bool = true
    @State private var is_user_same_as_event_creator: Bool = true
    @State private var is_loading: Bool = true
    
    var event: Event?
    
    //    event
    @State private var location = ""
    @State private var description = ""
    @State private var state = "new"
    @State private var time: Date = Date()
    @State private var latitude:Double?
    @State private var longtitude:Double?
    
    @State private var event_applications:[EventApplication] = []
    @State private var event_applications_users:[User] = []

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    //    user
    @AppStorage("user_latitude") var user_latitude: Double?
    @AppStorage("user_longitude") var user_longitude: Double?
    @AppStorage("user_data") var user_data: Data?
    
    private var event_util = EventUtil()
    private var user_util = UserUtil()
    private var event_application_util = EventApplicationUtil()
    
    @State private var is_date_selected: String?

    
    init(event: Event?) {
        if let event = event {
            print("Event passed")
            let userData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: user_data ?? Data())
            
            self.event = event
            
            
            self._location = State(initialValue: event.location ?? "")
            self._description = State(initialValue: event.description ?? "")
            self._state = State(initialValue: event.state ?? "")
            self._latitude = State(initialValue: event.latitude ?? 0.0)
            self._longtitude = State(initialValue: event.longitude ?? 0.0)
            let date_formatter = DateFormatter()
            date_formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
            let eventTime = date_formatter.date(from: event.time)
            self._time = State(initialValue: eventTime ?? Date())
            
            
            self._is_user_same_as_event_creator = State(initialValue: event.created_by == userData?.created_by)
            
            self._is_read_only = State(initialValue: is_user_same_as_event_creator)
            
            
            
        } else {
            self.event = nil
            self._is_user_same_as_event_creator = State(initialValue: true)
            self._is_read_only = State(initialValue: false)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        Form {
            if !is_loading && event_applications.count > 0 {
                Section(header: Text("Users that applied")) {
                    List {
                        ForEach(event_applications.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: UserEditView(user: event_applications_users[index], onButtonPress: handleButtonPress),
                                label: {
                                    Text(event_applications_users[index].name)
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit Event")
        .onAppear {
            handle_get_event_applications()
        }

    }
    

    
    func handleButtonPress(_ action: ButtonAction) {
        switch action {
        case .yes:
            // Handle "Yes" button press
            break
        case .no:
            // Handle "No" button press
            break
        case .maybe:
            // Handle "Maybe" button press
            break
        }
    }
    
    func handleSelection() {
           // Implement the action you want to perform when the button is selected
           print("User selected something")
       }
    
    func handle_save_event() {
        if user_longitude == nil {
            return
        }
        event_util.create_event(location: location, description: description, time: time,user_latitude:user_latitude,user_longitude:user_longitude) { (result: Result<Data, Error>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                // Handle success
                print("Success: \(data)")
                is_event_saved = true // Set the flag to true to dismiss the view
            case .failure(let error):
                // Handle error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    func handle_get_event_applications(){
        event_application_util.get_event_applications_by_id(event_id: event?.id ?? "") { events_applications, error in
            if let events_applications = events_applications {
                print("events_applications: ",events_applications)
                self.event_applications = events_applications
                handle_get_event_applicants_users()

            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching event applications: \(error)")
                self.is_loading = false
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func handle_get_event_applicants_users(){
        user_util.get_users_from_ids(users_ids: event_applications.map{ $0.created_by} ) { events_applications, error in
            if let events_applications = events_applications {
                print("events_applications: ",events_applications)
                self.event_applications_users = events_applications
                self.is_loading = false
            } else if let error = error {
                self.is_loading = false
                
            }
        }
        }
    
    
  
}
```

Comment: Can you please remove the extraneous code and post a [mre]?

Comment: you have to tie your button action to each button. Look into Compostable Architecture it seems like you are trying to recreate it. You should also try some basic tutorials you obviously have experience with web developerment languages and SwiftUI is very different.

Comment: Also worth noting that indices are not safe to use with `ForEach`. You should be using `Identifiable` data